# Is it possible to turn a playlist into an .iso file?

Tags: windows, itunes, iso-image, music

My dad has had a question he's been trying to find the answer to for a while and I tried to help him find the answer but I too have had a hard time. I've spent all day googling for a solution and finally all out of ideas.

**Problem**: My dad wants to know if it's possible to take an itunes playlist an turn it into an .iso (without having to use a physical cd in the process)

**What I've tried**: I discovered this is possible to solve with mac but he has windows. On mac although I haven't tried it I've read that you have to use a piece of software called virtual-cd-rw. On Windows most of virtual drives aren't even seen by itunes. The closest I got was with a program called virtual cd which itunes was able to see but wanted a blank disc to be inserted. I thought of searching for an alternative to itunes in the sense of being a music organizer and virtual cd burner but I don't think that would suffice for my dad since he uses it for his ipod. At the time of writing this I wondered if drag and drop would work but then I found this http://lifehacker.com/281055/drag-and-drop-an-itunes-playlists-songs-into-a-folder Since one of the commenters said that dragging and dropping would move the actual music and not just copy that shot down the idea I had of doing that in combination with imgburn which can take a folder of music files and turn them into n .iso file.

I'd really like to solve this issue for my dad and am surprised how to difficult it has proven to be in finding a solution.

**Update**: Due to a comment I've decided to clarify something. The reason it needs to be itunes and not another program is because my dad doesn't want to have recreate all the playlists he already made and the reason it needs to be an iso file is because my dad wants to share his personal vinyl rips he made from his own vinyl with his brother and he doesn't want to go through having to copy the files from each individual directory nor does he want his brother to have to do the reverse on their end. Therefore he wants the order of the playlist to be retained.

Comment: This sound like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What real issue are you trying to solve? Why do you need an iso when you have a playlist? Just sync the playlist to the  iPod.

Comment: I don't know as I never asked my dad that. I too want to know but regardless of the reason I'm asking to find out if it can be solved because at the moment I feel like the only way it can theoretically be solved is if I somehow wrote a program that's an extension of itunes. (which I have no idea how to do since itunes isn't open-source)

Comment: The thing is you can't play an iso on an ipod so the whole exercise is rather pointless.

Comment: Made an update to the question in answer to what you're asking.